# how to change the color of a div by clicking specific radio button

Tags: javascript

Hello everyone at stackoverflow community

I try to create a function of native javascript.....
i want to change the background-color of specific invoice_wrapper div to red  if i click the radioyes button 
or green if i click radiono button

i want to do this by this keyword

how can i do this by native javascript not any library please

good luck.....

```
    <?php foreach($fetches AS $electricities): ?>

<div class="invoice_wrapper">

<?php if($electricities->paid == "Yes"): ?>

Yes: <input onclick="" class="radioyes" type="radio" name="paid" value="<?php echo $electricities->paid; ?>" checked>
No: <input onclick="" class="radiono" type="radio" name="paid" value="No">

<?php else: ?>

Yes: <input onclick="" class="radioyes" type="radio" name="paid" value="<?php echo $electricities->paid; ?>">
No: <input onclick="" class="radiono" type="radio" name="paid" value="No" checked>

<?php endif; ?>

</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use [**`querySelectorAll`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select the elements with specified selector.
- [**`:checked`**](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector will only select `checked` elements to set `background` initially.
- [**`Array.from`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to cast `Array-like-object` to `array`
- Iterate through elements using [**`Array#forEach`.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [**`classList.add/remove`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to play with `classes`

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.invoice_wrapper [type="radio"]');
var elemsInit = document.querySelectorAll('.invoice_wrapper [type="radio"]:checked');
var handler = function(elem) {
  elem.parentNode.classList.remove('red', 'green');
  if (elem.value === 'Yes') {
    elem.parentNode.classList.add('green');
  } else {
    elem.parentNode.classList.add('red');
  }
};
Array.from(elemsInit).forEach(handler);
Array.from(elems).forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('change', handler.bind(null, elem));
});
```

```css
.invoice_wrapper {
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}
.green {
  background: green;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="invoice_wrapper">
  Yes:
  <input class="radioyes" type="radio" name="paid1" value="Yes" checked>No:
  <input class="radiono" type="radio" name="paid1" value="No">
</div>

<div class="invoice_wrapper">
  Yes:
  <input class="radioyes" type="radio" name="paid2" value="Yes">No:
  <input class="radiono" type="radio" name="paid2" value="No" checked>
</div>
```

Comment: @mohdadawe, What is so difficult ?

Comment: What  is forEach  that you use in this function  do you mean for loop

Comment: I am new in Javascript

Comment: @mohdadawe  I have provided reference for it as well.

Comment: Thanks you very much rayon

Comment: @mohdadawe, Kindly [accept and up-vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) the best solution which has solved the purpose :) __Happy coding!__